# React-native Command failed: gradlew.bat app:installDebug -PreactNativeDevServerPort=8081

Tags: react-native

when starting my react-native project `react-native run-android` I get the error in the picture.[image]

on the internet `cd ./android ./gradlew.bat installDebug` command says it will repair but this command does not work thanks you so much [image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found out that the problem was with the java version, I upgraded the installed 1.8 version to 11 and the windows advanced site settings > environment variables in the picture.
my JAVA_HOME
i updated[image]